# Uploaded code not executing on the Nucleo H745ZI

Tags: stm32, nucleo

This is a question for people familiar with the Nucleo H745ZI, or H7 in common.

When I received the Nucleo H745ZI it had the blinking LED program on it. This was working fine.

Now I'm trying to upload my own program and it's not doing anything at all. Both the LEDs and UART aren't giving output. This is after generating a fresh project in CubeMXIDE. Everything default.

My code;

```
  HAL_GPIO_TogglePin (GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_14);
  HAL_Delay(50);
  HAL_GPIO_TogglePin (GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_1);
  HAL_Delay(100);
  HAL_GPIO_TogglePin (GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_0);
  HAL_Delay(200);
 
  uint8_t buff[4] = {3, 4, 5, 6};
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, buff, sizeof(buff), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
```

I've tried both building and manually uploading the CM7.bin file and using the debug tool in the CubeMXIDE. Both not working.

Firmware has been updated.

By the way, does anyone know where I can find this default program?

Answer (score 0):

Found solution for NUCLEO-H745ZI-Q:
Do not drag and drop CM4 or CM7 bin file in Nucleo board storage.   Use STM32CubeIDE to upload program to each one.  Use default NUCLEO-H745ZI-Q board settings when creating new projects.  You only need to connect ST Link USB.

Answer (score 0):

When we are working on NUCLEO-H745ZI-Q remember that we have a dual core architecture so we must configure the peripherals for each core in the CubeMX project or in the Cube IDE configuration window on the tab of System Core > GPIO for the LEDS and the same for UART

Once you have generate the code, then you'll core M4 and M7 subproject directory whit their own source and main.c files.

Also, on my experience, I have notice that you must compile and upload both core-main.c-program to run your code on board, specially when you program at core M4 because the code uploaded does not execute until you upload M7 program.

Comment: Hi JCTV. Please use the comments section for comments.